# How to store the last displayed value from the console?

Tags: python, dymola, crash

My python script passes changing inputs to a program called "Dymola", which in turn performs a simulation to generate outputs. Those outputs are stored as numpy arrays "out1.npy".

```
for i in range(0,100):
    #code to initiate simulation
    print(startValues, 'ParameterSet:', ParameterSet,'time:', stoptime)
    np.save('out1.npy', output_data)
```

Unfortunately, Dymola crashes very often, which makes it necessary to rerun the loop from the time displayed in the console when it has crashed (e.g.: 50) and increase the number of the output file by 1. Otherwise the data from the first set would be overwritten.

```
for i in range(50,100):
    #code to initiate simulation
    print(startValues, 'ParameterSet:', ParameterSet,'time:', stoptime)
    np.save('out2.npy', output_data)
```

Is there any way to read out the 'stoptime' value (e.g. 50) out of the console after Dymola has crashed?

Comment: logging data willl help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the dymola interface to simulate your model. If so, why don't you use the return value of the dymola.simulate() function and check for errors.
E.g.:

```
crash_counter = 1
from dymola.dymola_interface import DymolaInterface
dymola = DymolaInterface()
for i in range(0,100):
    res = dymola.simulate("myModel")
    if not res:
        crash_counter += 1
    print(startValues, 'ParameterSet:', ParameterSet,'time:', stoptime)
    np.save('out%d.npy'%crash_counter, output_data)
```

As it is sometimes difficult to install the DymolaInterface on your machine, here is a useful [link](https://github.com/RWTH-EBC/AixLib/wiki/How-to:-Dymola-Python-Interface).
Taken from there:

> The Dymola Python Interface comes in the form of a few modules at \Dymola 2018\Modelica\Library\python_interface. The modules are bundled within the dymola.egg file.

To install:

> The recommended way to use the package is to append the \Dymola 2018\Modelica\Library\python_interface\dymola.egg file to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can do so from the Windows command line via set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Dymola 2018\Modelica\Library\python_interface\dymola.egg.

If this does not work, append the following code before instantiating the interface:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join('PATHTODYMOLA',
                                'Modelica',
                                'Library',
                                'python_interface',
                                'dymola.egg'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming dymola is a third-party entity that you cannot change.

One possibility is to use the `subprocess` module to start dymola and read its output from your program, either line-by-line as it runs, or all after the created process exits. You also have access to dymola's exit status.

If it's a Windows-y thing that doesn't do stream output but manipulates a window GUI-style, and if it doesn't generate a useful exit status code, your best bet might be to look at what files it has created while or after it has gone. `sorted( glob.glob("somepath/*.out"))` may be useful?